# How to create Google Analytics Custom filter to show only traffic from UK?

Tags: google-analytics

I created a new filter, defined it as 'Custom filter', but now what??
Which option do I have to use: 'Include' or 'Advanced', and what is the syntax/pattern to UK only?

Thanks!
Michelle.

Answer (score 3):

Include -> Filter Pattern -> United Kingdom

[image]

The syntax of how the country is listed should follow how the country is listed in the Map Overlay report.

[image]

Comment: Thank  you! I just added it, and waiting to see what comes up :)